# My package won't build because of a missing package

Tags: apt

I am using Jenkins to build packages for our network. Right now the build fails because of the following error:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_3.13.0-55.94_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
```

I have a few questions about this. When I install the package (pbuilder) on my own in a vagrant box it goes fine, and this package is never even called. Second question is how could I resolve this when the package seems like it is basically gone for the time being? If I go to the IP I land on a typical 'It Works!' page as if they had just set up the server for the first time.

Am I basically screwed right now?

Comment: See [Ubuntu Package Search Results](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-libc-dev).  As drewbenn pointed out, the package referenced is stale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just need to `apt-get update`. Your package cache is out of date and requesting an older version that is no longer available.

Comment: yes this was the problem. i don't really have access to the jenkins builder but I included and `update` into the shell commands and it fixed the problem.